# Wildfly 20 Upgrade and OpenJRE 8 - Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java, wildfly

We are using openjre-8.0.252.09-hotspot, upgraded from Wildfly 10 to Wildfly 20, and started facing following issue, although:

- jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar is already present in WEB-INF\lib
- rt.jar (in openjre) has: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

I have tried adding the following which did not work:

1. jaxb-api-2.1.jar to the lib.
2. used openjdk instead of openjre

**Why is the application not able to find the com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory class which is already present in rt.jar ?**
Is there something else that I am missing ?
I tried searching, but all the answers are related to java 9 and above, but no answers fro openjre-8.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory from [Module "deployment.myproject.war" from Service Module Loader]]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:141)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:314)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435)
    at org.apache.camel.spring.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler.createJaxbContext(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:187)
```

Comment: JAXB is already included with Wildfly.  I'll admit that I'm not sure why it worked in Wildfly 10 but I'd remove this and anything else that is part of standard JavaEE from being part of your .war file.

Comment: Hi Stdunbar, I have also tried removing jaxb-impl from application's web-inf/lib, but still getting the same error.

Comment: It's difficult to guess then with what's here.  You are apparently using camel and spring too.  Is there any way to reproduce this with a very small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RootCause:
One of the jar in application's WebInf/lib had jaxb.properties which had following entry:
`javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory`

Removing this resolved the issue.